# Require() in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, touchablehighlight

I work on an idea of select star and I'm stuck on a problem.
Here is my code :

```
export default class Star extends Component {
    render() {
        var starArray = [];
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            if (i < this.props.value) {
                imageSource = this.props.fullStar;
            } else {
                imageSource = this.props.emptyStar;
            }
            starArray.push(
            <View key={i}>
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => console.log("etoile : "+this.key)}>
                    <Image source={imageSource} style={{width: 25, height: 25}}/>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
              );
        }
        return (
            <View style={Styles.container}>
                {starArray}
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I would like when we press on a **star** to know what **star** is pressed, my **star**s are in an array and I don't know what **star** I pressed.

[image: it is the rendering]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the star number with the click callback.

```
export default class Star extends Component {
    handleClick(i){
        console.log("star number " + i);
    }
    render() {
        var starArray = [];
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            if (i < this.props.value) {
                imageSource = this.props.fullStar;
            } else {
                imageSource = this.props.emptyStar;
            }
            starArray.push(
            <View key={i}>
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.handleClick.bind(this,i)}>
                    <Image source={imageSource} style={{width: 25, height: 25}}/>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
              );
        }
        return (
            <View style={Styles.container}>
                {starArray}
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```